# SQL tricks: finding a value within a range across rows

Tags: sql, range, self-reference

I am using a database of exchange rates that has values valid only within specific dates.  For instance if I want to convert USD to EURO I have to use a particular exchange rate that falls within specific dates.  The exchange rate changes over time and it will eventually be replaced by another, more updated one.  Here is a sample of the exchange rate database I have:

```
Exchange_Rate_History
Valid-From  Exchange-rate  From-Currency  To-Currency
2012-04-16  0.8            USD            EUR
2012-04-18  0.82           USD            EUR
2012-04-20  0.81           USD            EUR
```

Now if you notice, I only have a 'Valid-From' date but I DO NOT HAVE a 'Valid-To' date.

Now I have another table that needs to be joined to the Exchange_Rate_History table.  This table contains shopping transactions

```
Purchases
Transaction-ID  Transaction-Date  Amount-In-USD
1               2012-04-16        100
2               2012-04-17        100
```

For the above two transactions we have two different dates, 16th and 17th April 2012.  BUT for both dates we need to use the exchange rate that is marked as being Valid-From 2012-04-16.  Since I only have a from date I cannot use a BETWEEN..AND to perform the join.  The following join is therefore not possible

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    Exchange_Rate_History
INNER JOIN Purchases ON (Purchases.Transaction-Date BETWEEN Exchange_Rate_History.Valid-From AND Exchange_Rate_History.???)
```

I was thinking of doing a self-join (recursive/self-referencing relationship) of the Exchange_Rate_History table so that I get two Valid-From columns next to each other.  The first Valid-From would be the original one while the second would be a vertically shifted one.  The resulting table would look like this:

```
Exchange_Rate_History
Valid-From  Exchange-rate  From-Currency  To-Currency Valid-From-1 (aliased to Valid-To)  
2012-04-16  0.8            USD            EUR         2012-04-18
2012-04-18  0.82           USD            EUR         2012-04-20
2012-04-20  0.81           USD            EUR
```

I would want to use the Valid-From-1 field as if it were a Valid-To field so that I can perform the SQL statement above. Notice now that the Valid-From field has the date 16th April while the Valid-To has the 18th April.   However at this stage I do not know how to do the recursive relationship that 'shifts' the records vertically!

Any help please?  This is not an easy one!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each exchange rate is valid starting on `valid-from` and ending when the next one starts,
you want to select the most recent `valid-from` which is earlier than the transaction date. That will be the row which was current at that time.

You can directly obtain the exchange rate for a transaction with a subquery as follows. Assuming variables `@currencyFrom`, `@currencyTo` and `@transactionDate`:

```
select top 1 
  exchange-rate 
from Exchange_Rate_History erh
where erh.currency-from = @currencyFrom
  and erh.currency-to = @currencyTo
  and erh.valid-from < @transactionDate
order by erh.valid-from desc
```

You can put that in a subquery to obtain the rate for a transaction by substituting outer field names for variables.

For example:

```
Select p.Transaction-ID, p.Transaction-Date, p.Amount-in-USD,
(select top 1 
  exchange-rate 
from Exchange_Rate_History erh
where erh.currency-from = 'USD'
  and erh.currency-to = 'CHF'
  and erh.valid-from < p.Transaction-Date
order by erh.valid-from desc) as exchange-rate,
(select top 1 
  exchange-rate 
from Exchange_Rate_History erh
where erh.currency-from = 'USD'
  and erh.currency-to = 'CHF'
  and erh.valid-from < p.Transaction-Date
order by erh.valid-from desc) * p.Amount-In-USD as Amount-In-CHF


from Purchases p
```

You will probably find this performs just fine even though you are doing two subqueries. You could rewrite it to avoid that but it will probably not be worth the effort.

There is no way to avoid the loop join, but your clustered index should be on `currency-from`, `currency-to`, `valid-from`, then it should perform OK. If you cannot change the clusttered index create an idex on those fields and include the `exchange-rate` in the index as well - that will also give as good performance.

Comment: Nice idea. I would clean up the two subqueries by creating a table function that either returns just the rate at that time, or the rate and amount*rate. Then using cross apply, passing in the transaction date and the currency you want to get you the rate. Then you can simply select P.Amount, TableFunction.Rate, P.Amount*TableFunction.Rate (Or TableFunction.ConvertedAmount)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetExchangeRate
(
  @TransactionDate  DATETIME,
  @FromCurrency VARCHAR(3),
  @ToCurrency VARCHAR(3)
 )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT TOP 1
        Rate
    FROM
        ExchangeRates
    WHERE
        FromCurrency = @fromCurrency
    AND ToCurrency = @toCurrency
    AND ValidFrom <= @transactionDate
    ORDER BY
        ValidFrom DESC
```

Then:

```
SELECT
    Purchases.ID,
    Purchases.Transaction-Date,
    Purchases.Amount-In-USD,
    ExchangeRate.Rate,
    Purchases.Amount-In-USD * ExchangeRate.Rate As ConvertedAmount
FROM
    Purchases
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetExchangeRate(Purchases.Transaction-Date, 'USD', 'EUR') ExchangeRate
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
SELECT *
    , (SELECT TOP 1 Valid-From
        FROM Exchange_Rate_History ex2
        WHERE ex2.From-Currency = ex1.From-Currency
            AND ex2.To-Currency = ex1.To-Currency
            AND ex2.Valid-From > ex1.Valid-From
        ORDER BY ex2.Valid-From ASC) Valid-To
FROM Exchange_Rate_History ex1
```

There are probably many other options too on how to handle it, but this is a simple sub-query method.

Method 2:

Using a cross apply might make it more efficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM Exchange_Rate_History ex1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Valid-From
        FROM Exchange_Rate_History ex2
        WHERE ex2.From-Currency = ex1.From-Currency
            AND ex2.To-Currency = ex1.To-Currency
            AND ex2.Valid-From > ex1.Valid-From
        ORDER BY ex2.Valid-From ASC) Valid-To
```

Comment: Please not that this will force a loop-join on SQL Server.

Comment: The problem with this is that the subquery will be run on each and every resulting row and I have hundreds of thousands of rows to join.

Comment: @prince Added method 2 using a CROSS APPLY to get the To date.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions anable you to use the lag() and lead() functions:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path='tmp';

CREATE TABLE exchange
        ( valid_from DATE NOT NULL
        , cur_from CHAR(3)
        , cur_to CHAR(3)
        , rate FLOAT
        ,PRIMARY KEY(cur_from,cur_to,valid_from)
        );
INSERT INTO exchange(valid_from,rate,cur_from,cur_to) VALUES
  ('2012-04-16',  0.8,        'USD', 'EUR' )
, ('2012-04-18',  0.82,       'USD', 'EUR' )
, ('2012-04-20',  0.81,       'USD', 'EUR' )
, ('2012-04-16',  800,        'USD', 'YEN' )
, ('2012-04-18',  820,       'USD', 'YEN' )
, ('2012-04-20',  810,       'USD', 'YEN' )
        ;

WITH next AS (
        SELECT valid_from
        , lead (valid_from) OVER nxt AS valid_to
        , cur_from
        , cur_to
        , rate
        FROM exchange
        WINDOW nxt AS (
           PARTITION BY cur_from,cur_to
           ORDER BY cur_from,cur_to,valid_from)
           )
SELECT * from next
        ;
```

RESULT:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.exchange
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "exchange_pkey" for table "exchange"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
 valid_from |  valid_to  | cur_from | cur_to | rate 
------------+------------+----------+--------+------
 2012-04-16 | 2012-04-18 | USD      | EUR    |  0.8
 2012-04-18 | 2012-04-20 | USD      | EUR    | 0.82
 2012-04-20 |            | USD      | EUR    | 0.81
 2012-04-16 | 2012-04-18 | USD      | YEN    |  800
 2012-04-18 | 2012-04-20 | USD      | YEN    |  820
 2012-04-20 |            | USD      | YEN    |  810
(6 rows)
```

(Update: added the yen, and PARTITION BY)